# Adding role based access for URLs

Tags: java, security, struts

I am working on a legacy (struts 1.1 running in jdk 1.4 , tomcat 6)application and need advice for implementing user role based security.

A user u1 has a read/view permission while user u2 has write permission on certain action. E.g

Url for user u1 :

> http://www.somedomain.com:8080/app?key=12

(It shows the content related with key 12 from DB).

Url for user u2 :

> http://www.somedomain.com:8080/app?key=12&note=some note test

(It basically insert note value in DB for key 12)

Suppose if user u1 who has view rights, come to know the url used by u2, he can insert any malicious value for particular key, which he is not suppose to do.

Even though role based access to struts action class is in place , here the action class used by both users are same and only difference is url parameter.

Now I have to fix this issue, which is spread across thousands of action classes.So adding checking conditions in each and every action class will not be feasible.

I am thinking of writing a filter class which will read user role and allowed request parameter(with possible values like action='save' action='view') from a configuration file.

Are there any alternative solution approach?

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) - that lets you map roles to URLs using whatever authentication mechanism you like.

Comment: @MattR Adding a new technology would be the last choice, if I use Sprint wouldn't it require to port the entire user role managment system in to Sprint security?

Comment: You can use your existing users/roles, you need a lot of configuration, and an implementation of [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) that looks up your existing users.

Answer (score 0):

your best choice is to modify the action class and implement some check inside called method (you can mixup container role-based permissions)

```
public void perform(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String note = request.getParameter("note");

    if(!request.isUserInRole("writer") && note != null) throw new SecurityException("not allowed");

    ...
}
```

Comment: As I already mentioned it will not be practical to change 4k+ action classes.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your application, but I would try to apply `java declarative security` for my role based solution as much as possible.

If it is easy for you to use the java ee declarative security then go for it.
It is simple, flexible and using standards which will give you the safety you request and the ability to port your solution to different java web server providers.

Maybe a url rewriter (apache in front of the web application can help to reorganize); can split the destinations, and for that in your java web server set the url patterns which will expect different user roles for the `read/view` and `update/write` grantings permissions.

This will need some few changes to achieve, but you would definitely not need to change your 4k codebase and you will by this reach a clean solution.

*Search for* e.g. setting up role based security or java declarative security

some reading with demo...
http://www.thecoderscorner.com/team-blog/hosting-servers/17-setting-up-role-based-security-in-tomcat#.Us0eShoeK-Y